# Enviar text a base de datos mediante input hidden

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli, html-select

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente. Tengo un select con diferentes value numéricos asignados, y a la vez cada uno tiene un text correspondiente. Escribí una función javascript para poder enviar a mi base de datos la información de los text en lugar del value mediante PHP. Mi inconveniente es que no logro hacer que esto funcione correctamente, ya que no logro vincular la función con el input hidden mediante el cual envío los datos elegidos por el usuario a una base de datos. Adjunto el código correspondiente:

```php
<div class="loc1">
<p>Provincia</p>
<select name="provincia" id="provincia" onchange="cambia_localidad();ShowSelected();">
    <option value="0" selected>Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires</option>
    <option value="1">Provincia de Buenos Aires</option>                                
    <option value="2">Córdoba</option>
    <option value="3">Santa Fe</option>
    <option value="4">Mendoza</option>
    <option value="5">Tucumán</option>
    <option value="6">Entre Ríos</option>
    <option value="7">Salta</option>
    <option value="8">Misiones</option>
    <option value="9">Chaco</option>
    <option value="10">Corrientes</option>
    <option value="11">Santiago del Estero</option>
    <option value="12">San Juan</option>
    <option value="13">Jujuy</option>
    <option value="14">Río Negro</option>
    <option value="15">Chubut</option>
    <option value="16">Neuquén</option>
    <option value="17">Formosa</option>
    <option value="18">San Luis</option>
    <option value="19">Catamarca</option>
    <option value="20">La Rioja</option>
    <option value="21">La Pampa</option>
    <option value="22">Santa Cruz</option>
    <option value="23">Tierra del Fuego</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowSelected(){
        var provincia = document.getElementById('provincia');
        var selected = provincia.options[provincia.selectedIndex].text;
        console.log(selected);
    }
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="selected" name="selected" value="<?php echo $selected?>"></input>
</div>
```

**Envío de la información a una base de datos**

```php
<?php 
include 'php/conexion_be.php';
if(isset($_POST['publicar'])){
     $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
     $id = $_SESSION['id'];
     $provincia = $_POST['selected'];
  
     $query = "INSERT INTO anuncios(usuario, id, fecha, provincia)
                VALUES('$usuario', '$id', now(), '$provincia')";
                $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
?>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: si en tu base de datos trabajas con `id` para que necesitarias el nombre de la provincia? no esta esta ligadas a un tabla `lo mas recomendable` provincias donde si envias provincia 1 regresa `Provincia de Buenos Aires`

Comment: Necesito el text de la provincia ya que luego necesito imprimir ese text mediante un echo en mi web, es decir que se muestre la opción escogida por el usuario, pero no el value sino justamente el nombre de la provincia

Comment: y no, en base al `ID` puedes obtener ese `text`?

Comment: Disculpa, no entendí tu comentario. El ID no está vinculado con la selección de provincia, sino que es un dato necesario para mí para incluirlo en mi base de datos. Lo único que necesito es imprimir mediante un echo la provincia escogida por el usuario, pero que al realizar esa impresión se muestre el text de la provincia y no su value. Lo que necesito entonces sería cómo enviar, mediante el input hidden, a la base de datos el text de la provincia y no su value numérico que es lo que actualmente se envía.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para este caso te recomiendo hacer lo que expresa en el comentario Bryro y tengas una tabla con el nombre de las provincias dependiendo del id ya que es la forma mas adecuada para manejar esta información y que al momento en que hagas el insert, realices una consulta para traer solo el nombre de la provincia en especifico. Si no lo quieres hacer de esta manera la otra opción es que al momento de ejecutar la funcion showSelected() realices lo siguientes:

```
function ShowSelected(){
    var provincia = document.getElementById('provincia');
    var selected = provincia.options[provincia.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("selected").value = selected;
    console.log(selected);
}
```

Recuerda que javascript y php son dos cosas muy diferentes por lo que no puedes asignar una variable:

```
var selected = provincia.options[provincia.selectedIndex].text;
```

y despues llamarla en php como:

```
echo $selected;
```

Ten en cuenta que debes dejar como vacío el valor del input selected y una vez envíes el formulario debería llegar en el valor de selected el texto de la provincia seleccionada. Avísame si pudiste solucionarlo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funcionó a la perfección! Es exactamente lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @Luca Me alegro que te funcionara, te recomiendo leer el apartado de  [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus próximas preguntas no sean tan confusas para los demás usuarios, por suerte también soy nuevo en la plataforma y pude entender lo que necesitabas. Mucha suerte